# Joining Lists in R

Tags: r, list

I am trying to join two lists in R, but I really don't know how to do it. I need a way to join the to lists by adding only the elements that have a different name from the ones to the first list, say:

```
list1=list('a'=1,'b'=2,'c'=3,'d'=4,'e'=5);
list2=list('b'=10,'c'=100,'e'=98);
list3=OpErAtIoN(list1,list2)
```

And one gets that list3 is `list('a'=1,'b'=10,'c'=100,'d'=4,'e'=98)`

Do you know any way to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

This gives the same result as your example:

```
modifyList(list1, list2)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! What I was trying to do is to write a function with a really long set of attributes that I didn't wanted to be in the function definition, by this way I will be able to use the ellipsis to change only those attributes I want to change. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`setdiff` will show you which list items are in "list1" but not in "list2":

```
> setdiff(names(list1), names(list2))
[1] "a" "d"
```

You can use `[` in the usual way to extract the relevant information from "list1":

```
list1[setdiff(names(list1), names(list2))]
```

And then you can use `c` to put it all back together:

```
c(list1[setdiff(names(list1), names(list2))], list2)
# $a
# [1] 1
# 
# $d
# [1] 4
# 
# $b
# [1] 10
#
# $c
# [1] 100
# 
# $e
# [1] 98
```