# How can I partially update or merge a list in R?

Tags: r

Here is a R list:

```
list1 <- list(var1=1,var2=list(var21=1,var22=2,var23=list(var231=1,var232=0)))
```

Here is another R list:

```
list2 <- list(var1=3,var2=list(var22=0,var23=list(var232=1,var233=2)),var3=list(var31=1))
```

Now I want to update `list1` by `list2`, which should include updating existing values and introducing new values. As a result `var1`, `var22`, `var232`should be updated to the value specified in `list2`, and `var233`, `var3`, `var31` should be introduced as new entries. Therefore the updated list should be like:

```
list(var1=3,var2=list(var21=1,var22=0,var23=list(var231=1,var232=2,var233=2)),var3=list(var31=1))
```

It is very similar with default settings and user-specific settings. The default settings should be loaded and updated by user-specific settings. In my use, I just create a R list from a JSON file (`default.json`) as default settings and want to update the default settings by another list produced by another JSON file (`user.json`), like many programs do.

Is there an existing package or some simple/decent way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps, [joining lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558459/joining-lists-in-r/21558546) is helpful?

Comment: The solution `modifyList` works but this question should not be considered duplicate to "Combine lists while overriding values with same name in R" because here not only updating existing fields are required but the fields in a inner list are asked to be updated rather than the first-level inner list being fully replaced.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a `modifyList` for these purposes. Note that I corrected `list3` definition, there's a mistake in your desired output.

```
list4 <- modifyList(list1, list2)
list3 <- list(var1=3,var2=list(var21=1,var22=0,var23=list(var231=1,var232=1,var233=2)),var3=list(var31=1))
all.equal(list3, list4)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Well, guess I reinvented the wheel.  Thanks for presenting `modifyList` .

Comment: +1, good one to know.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Rgames> list1 <- list(var1=1,var2=list(var21=1,var22=2,var23=list(var231=1,var232=0)))
Rgames> list2 <- list(var1=3,var2=list(var22=0,var23=list(var232=1,var233=2)),var3=list(var31=1))
Rgames> matchname<-intersect(names(list1),names(list2))
Rgames> diffname<-setdiff(names(list2),names(list1))
Rgames> for (j in c(matchname,diffname)) list1[[j]]<-list2[[j]]
Rgames> list1
$var1
[1] 3

$var2
$var2$var22
[1] 0

$var2$var23
$var2$var23$var232
[1] 1

$var2$var23$var233
[1] 2



$var3
$var3$var31
[1] 1
```

`intersect` finds all elements in both sets, so that I can replace them in `list1`.  `setdiff` finds elements in `list2` and not in `list1` so I can add them.  In reality, you could just do `for(j in names(list2)) list1[[j]] <- list2[j]]` but I expanded it to show ways you could do slightly different merging.